# How to select unique values from a table and insert it into another table in firebird?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, firebird

I have 2 tables in firebird, one of the tables contains the duplicate ID's and the other one only the unique ones. So, I want to use a procedure to select the unique ID's from the duplicates table and insert those into the unique table. But, I don't really know how, can anyone help me?

EDIT: Here is an example:

There are 2 tables

```
             ## GASFLESSEN ##            
ID CODE SUCCESS TARE_WEIGHT FILLING_NOZZLE      //< Column "CODE" contains those unique ID's.

           ## READINGS ##
      ID CODE_ID READING_TIME                   //< Column "CODE_ID" contains the duplicate ID's
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: `select * from table2`

Comment: Ah, my post was not really clear. I've edited it. I want to select the unique values from the duplicates table and insert those into the table containing the unique id's.

Comment: Still not clear. Could a "unique ID from the duplicates" already exist in the unique table?

Comment: Oh.. yeah. I am sorry, still new to firebird. But, isn't there a way to do this? I've tried using a query but that will only run the command once. Is there a way to keep the unique table unique while adding new unique id's to it??

Comment: Of course you can do this, but to give you the best possible answer it is better to give more complete information.

Comment: Alright, I gave an example hope you guys understand it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get list of "unique" ID-s in the table where there is dublicates then use `DISTINCT`, ie

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM d
```

Now if you want to further restrict the resultset to records which have a `id` not yet in the "unique table" either join the tables or use `NOT EXISTS` ie

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM d WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM u WHERE u.id = d.id)
```

Comment: This works, I will wait till there are more answers and choose the best answer. If not I will choose yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure CopyUniqueFromData;
declare var_id integer;
  for 
    select distinct id from d into :var_id 
  do begin
    insert into u (id) values (:var_id);
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. In addition to [the answer of ain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566414/466862) this can also be done using [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```
MERGE INTO table_unique
    USING (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_duplicates) src
    ON table_unique.id = src.id
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (id) values (src.id);
```

Comment: What table/column is supposed to be 'src'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KRS-One `src` is an alias for the query `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_duplicates` (in the `USING` part of the merge) as a reminder that that is the source of the data.